# Insert MongoDB document with an objectId that existed in the past

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I've a bunch of collections (12) and I need to rename many fields of them. I can't do it live in the database, all I can do is download and reupload a dump of it.

So I've downloaded the collection with mongodump manipulated the data and I'm planning to use mongorestore to push it back on the database.

I'm wondering what will happen then with ObjectIds.. I know that an objectId is unique throughout the database so I'm thinking about deleting all the old data right before using mongorestore, is it ok or will I still have problems with the ids?

Comment: Why you can not do it live? What is the problem?

Comment: I've been asked to work offline since is a production db, there's no technical limitation as far as I know.

Comment: Otherwise I'd have used `$rename` on fields and `renameCollection`  on collections

Comment: Exactly because it is production and it is worked app you need to perform upgrade and migrate data by application itself step by step.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify any value for MongoID whatever you want. You even can use string instead of MongoID.

If you have production app you need to perform upgrade and migrate data by application itself step by step.

If you have one proccess singlethreaded application or if you can run your app in that way - it is most simple case. Else you need synchronization service.

Be carefull with async/await and promises and so on asyncronous processes. They receive and have in memory one the data in one time and continue process with that data in another time, and it need to have in mind that.

You need to do:

- modify service to be ready to both data format
- create modification code which will go through all the data and migrate it
- modify service to be ready only to new data format once all the data migrate done

Comment: Maybe I haven't been clear: I'm not planning on changing the objectIds but pushing back the original ones

Comment: This mean you can do anything, If you have object with id, you can update it, or you can delete and create same with same id. And so on. But most probably it is not good approach at all. Describa problem more carefully and to make possible community be more clear and solve task according your problem.